# How to run CoroutineWorker synchronously with Android WorkManager?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing, android-workmanager

I use `WorkManager` in my app to chain multiple `CoroutineWorkers` together. I am trying to test my app and have these workers run synchronously before continuing with rest of test.

As `CoroutineWorker` is a suspend function it does not use the `SynchronousExecutor()` provided to the workmanager `Configuration`. The [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker) mentions that `CoroutineContext` can be provided to customise the thread the `CoroutineWorker` is run on.

How can I provide a `CoroutineContext` and have the worker run synchronously with the test code?

```kotlin
@Test
fun LaunchLongRunningCoroutineworkersWithWorkManager_FailsDueToAsynchronosity() {
    hiltRule.inject()
    context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
    val config = Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(delegatingWorkerFactory)
        .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
        .build()
    WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)

    val workRequest1 = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LongRunningCoroutineWorker1>()
        .build()

    val workRequest2 = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LongRunningCoroutineWorker2>()
        .build()

    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    workManager.beginUniqueWork("WORKNAME",ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest1)
        .then(workRequest2)
        .enqueue()

    val workInfo1 = workManager.getWorkInfoById(workRequest1.id).get()
    val workInfo2 = workManager.getWorkInfoById(workRequest1.id).get()

    /*fails expected: State.SUCCEEDED was: State.RUNNING*/
    assertThat(workInfo1.state).isEqualTo(WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) 
    assertThat(workInfo2.state).isEqualTo(WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED)
}
```

```kotlin
class LongRunningCoroutineWorker1(
    val context: Context,
    val parameters: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            /*simulate long work*/
            delay(5000)
            Result.success()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the [`TestInitHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/testing/WorkManagerTestInitHelper) with `CoroutineWorkers` (or `RxWorker`). That helper function has been built for Worker classes.

WorkManager v2.1 introduces a new set of APIs to support a simpler way to test ListenableWorker classes and, as a consequence, CoroutineWorker. In our code we're going to use one of these new API: [TestListenableWorkerBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/TestListenableWorkerBuilder).

Additional information is available in [WorkManager's testing guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing-worker-impl#testing-listenableworker-and-its-variants) and a sample is available in the [coroutine codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#11), that also covers WorkManager.

In your case you should have something like:

```kotlin
@Test
fun LaunchLongRunningCoroutineworkersWithWorkManager_FailsDueToAsynchronosity() {
    hiltRule.inject()
    context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

    val worker1 = TestListenableWorkerBuilder<LongRunningCoroutineWorker1>(context)
                  .setWorkerFactory(delegatingWorkerFactory)
                  .build()

    // "Manually" start the work
    val result1 = worker1.startWork().get()
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(Result.success())

    val worker2 = TestListenableWorkerBuilder<LongRunningCoroutineWorker2>(context)
                  .setWorkerFactory(delegatingWorkerFactory)
                  .build()

    // "Manually" start the work
    val result2 = worker1.startWork().get()
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(Result.success())
}
```

Comment: What if I am calling my `CoroutineWorkers` from an end to end UI test i.e. I am controlling the UI, simulating clicks from the user, and not able to 'manually' call the workers like above. My initial thought is to somehow inject the `TestListenableWorker`. What is the best way to handle this case?

Comment: In this case you are not testing the worker, you are testing the logic that enqueue the worker... 
If you really really want to do that (test end to end executing the CoroutineWorker syncronously) an option could be to inject the CoroutineScope that you want to use in the CoroutineWorker. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any injection of scope in this link? Also, I thought running `CoroutineWorker` in end to end tests would be a fairly routine thing, however from your response above it sounds like I am doing some kind of code smell?

Comment: Personally I see end to end tests as something where you expect that everything is executed in a sequence. For this reason I can understand that you want to test that work is enqueued, but WorkManager could execute your tasks in the future (not immediately). If you expect that the task is executed immediately, you may have better options: https://developer.android.com/guide/background